# Windows Phone 7, Animation & Styling

Tags: c#, expression-blend, windows-phone, windows-phone-7

I have just started Windows Phone 7 development so I don't know a lot. I have 2 questions.

1) How to apply Any animation during page change, meaning Navigating to another page.
I tried the instruction given [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170308/windows-phone-7-navigation-animation)

---

2) I have to change the background image of a button on click event. I did exactly as written [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/64a0075b-5665-4729-906c-30b0f420810e)
 but what ever changes I do it applies to all "Normal/Click/Disabled" how can I define different styles for different events.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) you tried which anaswer and *what happened*?  2) you need to be a lot clearer with what you mean by "different styles for different events", as your first sentence says you want to change it on the click event.  What do you actually want to do?  (also, this is probably 2 questions, not one)

Comment: I think i wrote "I have 2 Questions". For your question about which answer I tried: For Question # 1, I merged the question and the selected answer. For Question # 2, I want to set different background of the button on Click State of button and for Normal State.

Answer (score 2):

**for Question 2**, see: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-can-t-i-change-the-background-of-my-button-on-a-click-event.aspx

particularly the sections about the different visual states for the button.

**As for question 1**, it isn't a question.  It is a statement:  "I want X.  I tried Y."   There's no explanation of what about Y didn't work, or why you're asking about it even though you've linked to another question.  did you look at the other answer that uses the Silverlight Toolkit which has more than 2x the votes of the accepted answer?  What *specificly* isn't working?

Comment: please just forgot about what I tried can you tell me how to apply animation on page change. Thanks.

Comment: see the above links, and the links you posted yourself.  they both explain how to do what you want.  Personally, i use the silverlight toolkit's transitions, as explained in the second answer of the linked question you asked.  We can't do *everything* for you, this is a questions and answers site, not rent-a-coder.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) try this [Clarity.PageTransitionSample](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/10/13/wp7-page-transitions-sample/) , it have sample of many different transition style with source code to download.

For 2) try [Change a button's background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click)

Not very sure what you want, hope that helps!